# How do you strip substrings in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to replace/duplicate a substring, between two delimeters -- e.g.,:

`"This is (the string) I want to replace"`
I'd like to strip out everything between the characters `(` and `)`, and set that substr to a variable -- is there a built in function to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do:

```
my_string = "This is (the string) I want to replace"

p my_string.split(/[()]/) #=> ["This is ", "the string", " I want to replace"]

p my_string.split(/[()]/)[1] #=> "the string"
```

Here are two more ways to do it:

```
/\((?<inside_parenthesis>.*?)\)/ =~ my_string 
p inside_parenthesis #=> "the string"

my_new_var =  my_string[/\((.*?)\)/,1]
p my_new_var  #=> "the string"
```

Edit - Examples to explain the last method:

```
my_string = 'hello there'
capture = /h(e)(ll)o/ 

p my_string[capture]    #=> "hello"
p my_string[capture, 1] #=> "e"
p my_string[capture, 2] #=> "ll"
```

Comment: What does the `,1]` and `[1]` do in these?

Comment: Made some edits to show each step. Tell me if is it not clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
var = "This is (the string) I want to replace"[/(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))/]
var # => "the string"
```

Comment: This regex seems overly complex - care to explain why so much checking is needed?

Comment: Suppose you have `"foo (bar) bax (baz) foo"`. If you want to get `"bar) bax (baz"`, then go with the answer you selected. If you want `"bar"` instead, then my answer is the only one posted at this time that will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "This is (the string) I want to replace"

str.match(/\((.*)\)/)

some_var = $1  # => "the string"
```

Comment: Maybe just `some_var = str.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to remove or replace a substring as well as set a variable equal to that substring (sans the parentheses).  There are many ways to do this, some of which are slight variants of the other answers.  Here's another way that also allows for the possibility of multiple substrings within parentheses, picking up from @sawa's comments:

```
def doit(str, repl)
  vars = []
  str.gsub(/\(.*?\)/) {|m| vars << m[1..-2]; repl}, vars
end

new_str, vars = doit("This is (the string) I want to replace", '')  
new_str # => => "This is  I want to replace" 
vars    # => ["the string"] 

new_str, vars = doit("This is (the string) I (really) want (to replace)", '')  
new_str # => "This is  I  want" 
vars    # => ["the string", "really, "to replace"] 

new_str, vars = doit("This (short) string is a () keeper", "hot dang")  
new_str # => "This hot dang string is a hot dang keeper" 
vars    # => ["short", ""]
```

In the regex, the `?` in `.*?` makes `.*` "lazy".  `gsub` passes each match `m` to the block; the block strips the parens and adds it to `vars`, then returns the replacement string.  This regex also works:

```
/\([^\(]*\)/
```